# How to edit unity HoloLens Program from a Desktop App

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to figure out a way to edit the text in my Unity HoloLens program from a Desktop app live so that you will not have to download the program when you want to change it. I can not find any answers online but I know its possible since Microsoft Dynamic 365 Guides is able to do this. Has anyone done this before?

Ive built the Desktop app but have no idea on how to interface it with the program.

Comment: Do you mean send a message from the desktop application to the HoloLens application, and then the HoloLens application edits the text according to the received message? Have you tried some network libraries? If possible, please describe your desktop application and HoloLens application in detail.

Comment: My HoloLens Program is a scroll list with Radial buttons. I am wanting to be able to change the Text of the buttons from a desktop app live without having to download the program again.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like you probably need to build network communication between your desktop app and the HoloLens app. You can refer to [Which networking technology?' - UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/which-networking-technology) to implement it yourself according to your needs, or you can try to use some third-party network libraries.